# can i use google speech recognition api in my desktop application

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I want to know whether i can use speech recognition api of google for my desktop application. I have seen some example in which i have to convert the speech to a file and send to a url. But it will be little cumbersome task because in my application the user have to continuously submit his voice. So is there any other alternative to use google speech api. I am least interested to go with sphinx because its accuracy is very less and i dont know how to add new words in the dictionary and without adding it to dictionary it wont recognize new words. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that it is an API but you do not know if you can use it? I would say you can use any API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to ambient listening? I am actually working on some Voice Activity Detection algorithm with the Google Speech Recognition API. Although I haven't finished the algorithm yet, I've added a volume and frequency calculator so that you don't have to send requests to Google when the person is not talking. Here is the link to the source code.

https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api

(This isn't what I use, but it's simplistic. You can also add frequency threshold holds and stuff. I threw this code together so no guarantee it will work look at the example branch of the API.)

```
//package recognitionprocess;
//import org.jaudiotagger.audio.*;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;

import com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.GoogleResponse;
import com.darkprograms.speech.recognizer.Recognizer;

public class RecognitionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
        ambientListening();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void ambientListening() throws Exception{

        String filename = "tarunaudio.wav";//Your Desired FileName
        MicrophoneAnalyzer mic = new MicrophoneAnalyzer(AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE);
       mic.open();
        mic.captureAudioToFile(filename);
        final int THRESHOLD = 10;//YOUR THRESHOLD VALUE.
        int ambientVolume = mic.getAudioVolume();//
        int speakingVolume = -2;
        boolean speaking = false;
            for(int i = 0; i<1||speaking; i++){
                int volume = mic.getAudioVolume();
                System.out.println(volume);
                if(volume>ambientVolume+THRESHOLD){
                    speakingVolume = volume;
                    speaking = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("SPEAKING");
                }
                if(speaking && volume+THRESHOLD<speakingVolume){
                     break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(200);//Your refreshRate
            }
              mic.close();
            //You can also measure the volume across the entire file if you want
            //to be resource intensive.
            if(!speaking){
                 ambientListening();
            }
        Recognizer rec = new Recognizer(Recognizer.Languages.ENGLISH_US);
        GoogleResponse out = rec.getRecognizedDataForWave(filename);
        System.out.println(out.getResponse());
        ambientListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have some sample code how to execute it. It would be great for me because i have to show it to the client by the end of this month

Comment: There is an example branch you can download, but I'll edit my answer to include example code.

Comment: its giving lots of problem can you give me your mail id so that i can discuss my problem with you and send my code to you or you just send me a test mail on tarunvermacdac@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you an email, but I have yet to receive a reply.

Comment: It would be great if you would share the correct version **here** and edit your answer.

Comment: Could you please share the correct code for this ambient listening

Comment: @Skylion - This code works but at times it just hungs and doesn't respond, I'm guessing it's the encoding the wav to Flac. I noticed that the thread is sleeping but the sleep time is pretty short, even if you changed the sleep time and refresh rate - it gets stack a lot of times. Is that a known issue? Please take a look at the amazing google api demo: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html If you are using the same API that this demo is using, then shouldn't it be more accurate at detecting? Thanks tho.

Comment: How to execute this? i just downloaded the code from github, but getting struggle on how to execute. Can you pl guide me ..